# Retrieving Data from Database and display it a view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am new to asp.net mvc.

I have a Client,Complaint and employee table.

When a Client register a complaint the client information should be automatically populated based on the client ID.

Can someone advice me how to do it. How to call that client detail from the Client table and populate it in my complaint view?

Comment: This question is far too broad to give a definitive answer in its current form. But here's a tip: Does the user need to log in as a particular client to register a complaint? If so then you can probably look up the request from the user info on the server side. If not, you probably need to ask the user for client info when registering the complaint.

Comment: Firstly the user would register, with his email and password. Then he will have to register him as a client. After registering as a client he will be able to register the complaint.